# remove the first characters of each string in a foreach

Tags: php

How can I remove the first characters `characters_to_eliminate` of each string in a `foreach` loop?
EDIT: `characters_to_eliminate` are 3 random characters, they are not always the same.
In line 6 I try:

```
$val = substr($val, 3);
```

but only removes the first 3 characters of the first value in the array.

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ary = explode($delimiters[0],$string);
    array_shift($delimiters);
    if($delimiters != NULL) {
        foreach($ary as $key => $val) {
            $ary[$key] = multiexplode($delimiters, $val);
        }
    }
    return  $ary;
}

// Example of use
$string = "characters_to_eliminate abc, characters_to_eliminate def: characters_to_eliminate ghi, characters_to_eliminate jkl";
$delimiters = Array(",",":");

$res = multiexplode($delimiters,$string);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `foreach($ary as $key => &$val)`

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede `$value` with `&`. In that case the value will be assigned by reference. (via http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php )

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$string = str_replace('characters_to_eliminate ', '', $string); // abc, def: ghi, jkl
```